# Question about instrument variable without an intercept in R

Tags: r

I have the following code for a 2SLS regression function without intercept, and the instruments are A and Z. I am confused about the 0 in the instrumental variable part. With and without 0 will lead a slightly difference in the estimate but I have no idea how it happens. I think the version with 0 is the correct one but I don't know why I need to put 0 in the right part. Can anyone help me? Thanks

`eq1 <-ivreg(Y~0+X+Z|0+A+Z)`

Comment: In normal regressions it is usually how you tell the model to not estimate an intercept, is this not the case here?

Comment: 0 is basically telling ivreg to not estimate the intercept